# Excess items in RecyclerView with header and footer

Tags: android

I have a list of items, the count of items is 5:

```
    List<ReviewResource> reviewsList = new ArrayList<ReviewResource>();
    ReviewResource r1 = new ReviewResource();
    r1.setText("1");
    reviewsList.add(r1);

    ReviewResource r2 = new ReviewResource();
    r2.setText("2");
    reviewsList.add(r2);

    ReviewResource r3 = new ReviewResource();
    r3.setText("3");
    reviewsList.add(r3);

    ReviewResource r4 = new ReviewResource();
    r4.setText("4");
    reviewsList.add(r4);

    ReviewResource r5 = new ReviewResource();
    r5.setText("5");
    reviewsList.add(r5);
```

There is my RecyclerView adapter:

```
public class ReviewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

    private static final int TYPE_HEADER = 0;
    private static final int TYPE_ITEM = 1;
    private static final int TYPE_FOOTER = 2;

    List<ReviewResource> listItems;

    public ReviewAdapter(List<ReviewResource> list) {
        listItems = list;
    }


    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        if (viewType == TYPE_HEADER) {
            View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.reviews_header_item, parent, false);
            return new VHHeader(v);
        } else if (viewType == TYPE_ITEM) {
            View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.reviews_list_item, parent, false);
            return new VHItem(v);
        } else if (viewType == TYPE_FOOTER) {
            View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.reviews_footer_item, parent, false);
            return new VHFooter(v);
        }
        throw new RuntimeException("there is no type that matches the type " + viewType + " + make sure your using types correctly");
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        if (holder instanceof VHHeader) {
            VHHeader header = (VHHeader) holder;
        } else if (holder instanceof VHItem) {
            VHItem item = (VHItem) holder;
            if (position + 1 < listItems.size()) {
                ReviewResource currentReview = listItems.get(position+1);
                item.reviewDescription.setText(currentReview.getText());
            }
        } else if (holder instanceof VHFooter) {
            VHFooter footer = (VHFooter) holder;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return listItems.size() + 1;
    }

    public ReviewResource getItem(int position) {
        return listItems.get(position);
    }

    class VHHeader extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView txtTitle;

        public VHHeader(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
        }
    }

    class VHItem extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView reviewDescription;
        TextView reviewTitle;

        public VHItem(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            reviewDescription = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.reviewer_text);
            reviewTitle = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.review_title);
        }
    }

    class VHFooter extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView mWriteAReviewFooter;
        TextView mViewAllFooter;

        public VHFooter(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            this.mWriteAReviewFooter = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.write_a_review_footer);
            this.mViewAllFooter = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.view_all_footer);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        if (position == 0) {
            return TYPE_HEADER;
        } else  if (position == getItemCount() - 1) {
            return TYPE_FOOTER;
        } else {
            return TYPE_ITEM;
        }
    }
}
```

**Expected Result**

Header

1

2

3

4

5

Footer

**Actual Result**

Header

3

4

5

empty item

Footer

Only items 3,4 and 5 are displayed in my `RecyclerView` with the empty row after the 5th item.

Why ?

Anyway, thank you!

Comment: Are you sure your header is not hiding item 1 and 2 underneath it? maybe add margin to it?

Comment: Yeap, I'm sure that header not overflow items. The header row is 5 times smaller than items row, and I'm played with the margins, I think there is problem in adapter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your getItemCount should be

```
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return listItems.size() + 2;//HEADER + FOOTER
}
```

add a method

```
 public int getDataCount() {
    return listItems.size();
}
```

and in `onBindViewHolder`

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    if (holder instanceof VHHeader) {
        VHHeader header = (VHHeader) holder;
    } else if (holder instanceof VHItem) {
        VHItem item = (VHItem) holder;
        int index = position - 1;// -1 to consider HEADER
        if (index < getDataCount()) {
            ReviewResource currentReview = listItems.get(index);
            item.reviewDescription.setText(currentReview.getText());
        }
    } else if (holder instanceof VHFooter) {
        VHFooter footer = (VHFooter) holder;
    }
}
```

hopefully this will work

Answer (score 1):

At First you are returning wrong item size in getItemCount()
it should be

```
   @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return listItems.size() + 2;
    }
```

+2 instead of +1

and Change:

```
if (position + 1 < listItems.size()) {
                ReviewResource currentReview = listItems.get(position+1);
                item.reviewDescription.setText(currentReview.getText());
            }
```

to :

```
ReviewResource currentReview = listItems.get(position-1);
                    item.reviewDescription.setText(currentReview.getText());
```